# yii2 form with multiple models

Tags: yii2

Trying to follow the book Yii2-Application-Development-Cookbook-Third-Edition
in chapter 4 receipe 8:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Yii2-Application-Development-Cookbook-Third-Edition/tree/master/Chapter04_Code/Recipe08
But the problem I am facing with is that it shows only the first order even when I enter in the address bar order nr 5, it shows the nr 1 order.[image][image]

[clink the link for the codes](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Yii2-Application-Development-Cookbook-Third-Edition/tree/master/Chapter04_Code/Recipe08)

Comment: Can you show your view file ?

Comment: Update you question and add your controller/action and view code please

Comment: all the codes in controller/action/ view are in the link provided above: [link](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Yii2-Application-Development-Cookbook-Third-Edition/tree/master/Chapter04_Code/Recipe08)

Answer (score 0):

This little code solved it:

```
$order = Order::find($id)->with('user','product')->where(['id' => $id])->one();
```